# Split a Pandas column into either 4 or 5 columns depending on contents

Tags: pandas, split, multiple-columns

I have an excel sheet with the following column name:

address_1

in this column, the data looks like this example:

100 Main Street, Atlanta, GA 30223

But sometimes, the data contains an extra bit of info such as:

100 Main Street, Suite 100, Atlanta, GA 30223

I have hundreds of rows in Pandas with this type of info and the info varies like my example.

I have columns ready to go, which I imported from my original excel sheet looking like this:

address_1, address_2, city, state, zip

I'd like the original address_1 to separate the data and place the info in the correct column.

Due to this being scraped from google maps, notice there is no comma between state and zip.

Any ideas on how to have Pandas split everything out correctly?

I've tried a simple string split and got an error:

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key